# Generate comments to explain the structure of a C++ program

Tags: c++, syntax, comments

Is there any (reasonably) straightforward way to generate comments to explain the structure of a C++ program? For example I'd like to take this code as input:

```
int main(){
cout << "Hello World!";
return 0;
}
```

and produce this as output:

```
int main(){
//create a function called main that returns an integer and takes no parameters.
cout << "Hello World!";
//print the string "Hello World" to the standard output.
return 0;
//the function main returns 0
}
```

If it were possible to do this, it might make (the syntax of any C++ program) slightly less daunting for beginners.

If this can't be done for C++ (with existing tools), are (any similar tools) available for other programming languages?

Comment: All of those comments are completely pointless to anyone who would be using them.

Comment: Why would someone need this? If it's written "int main()" I know, that it's a function that takes blah-blah-blah and so on.

Comment: I might need to provide a better example then. This would be best used as a tool for beginners as opposed to experienced programmers.

Comment: I think that's an interesting question, to inline documentation into the code. However I agree with the previous comment, that you should no push code with such comment.

Comment: This wouldn't be obvious to someone who was approaching C++ for the first time - that's why I asked this question. An automatic comment generation tool would be useful for explaining the syntax of pointers within a code sample (which can be quite daunting for beginners.)

Comment: It looks to me like the intent isn't to actually include such comments in the program. It's only to have some way for a beginner to ask "What does this syntax mean?" There are some limited solutions for specific thing, like cdecl.org for the declaration syntax, but nothing general. And this would not be trivial. Perhaps something could be built relatively easily (only relatively) on top of the Clang libraries for processing c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `cdecl` tool (and on-line version at http://cdecl.org/) to explain declarations. Take a look.

Comment: This is actually one of the things that I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your example is extremely verbose and would only make any source code completely unreadable. There are solutions out there which are less verbose but much more pertinent like www.doxygen.org/ which I hear is quite popular.

Answer (score 0):

What you put in your comments does not make much sense - the fact that function returns integer or takes no parameters is self-explanatory by function prototype. However, if you mean generally tools for auto-comments which explain how function works, there is something.

I am not sure if this works for C++ as it does for C#, but there is a Visual Studio addon called GhostDoc that generates "human-language" comments based on variables/functions/etc names and such.
You can see it in action here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aA4VZoVDQw (second part of the video).

Even if it does not exactly solve your problem, maybe it will give you a hint what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question, you would like a tool who 'explains' the code by injecting the appropriate documentation in each line.

As far as I could be interesting , as you say for beginner, and to run it on existing code, it's totally useless to write code that way (this is why you are getting downvotes).

Those comments are just duplicate of the existing codes and so, are totally useless. What happend if you change the code , and don't change the comments ? Worst, if you run again your tool, are you expecting it to remove the old comment or leave them both ?

Good comments should add useful information to the code (as coder intention, or trick to avoid etc... ) but reading loudly the code is just noise.

So to answer your question, I think no, there is no tool, to do it. However , some IDE might offer a similar functionality,  where you could have such information on a tooltips whilst hovering on a line of code, but definitely not as comment in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is literate programming? http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/cweb.html

Comment: Will this system be able to automatically generate comments for function calls, pointer declarations, etc.?

Comment: No, it is for verbose programming, where comments are in fact code.

Answer (score 0):

Comments should not describe what the code will do. The comment should explain,

- what was the intention, which task has to be performed
- what the programmer expects, why a specific branch will be taken
- why the programmer wrote the code in that way

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the intent isn't to actually include such comments in the program. It's only to have some way for a beginner to ask "What does this syntax mean?" There are some limited solutions for specific thing, like cdecl.org for the declaration syntax, but nothing general. And this would not be trivial. Perhaps something could be built relatively easily (only relatively) on top of the Clang libraries for processing c++.